# Git push pull clone commands on macOS don't do anything after upgrade to Monterey

Tags: git, macos, terminal, gitlab, macos-monterey

I recently upgraded to macOS Monterey and noticed that I cannot do any git commands that affect an onliene repo. Commands that are affected so far are

```
git push
git pull
git clone
```

All commands just output *notinng*. Literally. I type them in and there isn't even a error, even after several minutes, and the remote repo also doesn't get the push.

#### What I tried so far

I tried to run these commands with repos from Github and Gitlab, and with private and public repos. My ssh keys are in place, the remote URL's seem to be right, I'm not in detached HEAD mode, I reinstalled Xcode and Xcode developer tools, I upgraded git through Homebrew, I reinstalled git though Homebrew, I activated and deactivated my Firewall in my System Settings and now I tried to turn my Mac off and on again (it still didn't work).

#### What seems to work for now

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git push
```

this gives me a whole log, and the push succeeds.

```
13:56:35.495625 git.c:455               trace: built-in: git push
13:56:35.497727 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; ssh git@gitlab.com 'git-receive-pack '\''airshopers/storefront.git'\'''
13:56:43.997487 run-command.c:668       trace: run_command: .git/hooks/pre-push origin git@gitlab.com:airshopers/storefront.git
Everything up-to-date
```

In addition, it appears that the second `git push` I run after a computer restart works.

**Update** Adding verbose and trace flags also doesn't solve the problem, as that "workaround" randomly stops working and I see the previously mentioned behaviour again.

I'm really at the end of my knowledge, any tips are appreciated :)

Comment: Useful additional debugging: `which git` (may depends on shell), `type git` (similar). Also check your `core.pager` setting and if it's not set, whether `less` and/or `more` are working.

Comment: Thanks @torek, `which git` gives me the expected version, and less is in place too. I don't think it is related to just the output though, as the output works for `git log` etc. but all calls to remotes don't work.

Comment: Interesting. That suggests some problem(s) with ssh and/or libcurl. Are all your remotes ssh-access? That's at least more debug-able, since Git literally just runs `ssh` here, rather than having libcurl compiled in (compiled-in libraries bring in all the dynamic linker complexities).

Comment: Uhmm.. so I ran my `ssh-add` before just to make sure. But if it was due to ssh then it wouldn't even work even once. But e.g. when I restart my computer one call gets through, which means ssh shouldn't be the problem neither. But I'll still check ssh another time now.

Comment: Any ssh problem could be a networking problem, or multiple ssh versions being installed, or any number of other things. But it's somewhere to poke at, anyway.

Comment: Yep, it's related to `ssh`. Just ran a `ssh -T git@github.com` with same behaviour. Now I added an `https` remote for my gitlab repo and with that remote pushing works. I found https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430363/monterey-ssh-with-hardware-key-only-works-once but looks like openssh is not necessarily the solution. I'll keep digging..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The upgrade to Monterey seems to break macOS `ssh`. I solved this by installing openssh from Homebrew:

```
brew install openssh
```

The installation seems to also update the default `ssh` used, so `which ssh` now points to `/usr/local/bin/ssh` instead of the native one.

Also make sure to open a new terminal window, or freshly source your terminal. Otherwise in your current session native ssh will be used.

This seems to have fixed the issue, I'll mark this answer as accepted if I don't encounter any new issues here.